# Java Hibernate JPA Deleting OneToMany Relation And MapKeyJoinColumn Relation Object

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, one-to-many

I want to create and delete one of **ProductPrice**, 
update is working properly but others gives exception

**PRODUCT CLASS**

```
public class Product extends GenericEntity {
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "product", targetEntity = ProductPrice.class, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval=true)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)    
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE, region="ncStandardElements")
    private List<ProductPrice> productPrices = new ArrayList<ProductPrice>();

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "product", targetEntity = ProductPrice.class)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)    
    @MapKeyJoinColumn(name="CURRENCY_ID")
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE, region="ncStandardElements")
    private Map<Currency, ProductPrice> productPriceMap = new HashMap<Currency, ProductPrice>();
}
```

**PRODUCTPRICE CLASS**

```
public class ProductPrice extends GenericEntitySimple {

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Product.class, optional=false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PRODUCT_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    private Product product;
}




public void removeProductPrice(ProductPrice price){
    Product p = price.getProduct();
    //Map<Currency, ProductPrice> productPriceMap = p.getProductPriceMap();
    //productPriceMap.remove(price);

    List<ProductPrice> prices = p.getProductPrices();
    prices.remove(price);
    p.setProductPrices(prices);
    productDao.merge(p);
}
```

If price is created on same session, delete operation is successful, however, if it has created before present session, it throws this **error**:

```
Jun 13, 2013 3:26:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet appServlet threw exception
org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists: [com.netasoft.commerce.framework.catalog.model.ProductPrice#220]
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl$2.handleEntityNotFound(SessionFactoryImpl.java:435)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:233)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:285)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1090)
```

I dont get MapKeyJoinColumn completely, and I cannot find documentation about this situation. I think Map lists cache cause this error. Any well prepared documentation suggestions is approved, also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last solution I have found is that;

The real problem is same object is in two different list cache. So, when you changed one of them, it cause error according to FetchType method you choose.

If you define FetchTypes as **FetchType.Eager**, **FetchType.SUBSELECT** and **CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE**, you can easily crud by changing objects in two side of cache! i.e. you want to delete one of price, you should remove it from `productPriceMap` & `productPrices` too. Then `merge product;` and it has finished!

```
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "product", targetEntity = ProductPrice.class, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval=true)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)    
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE, region="ncStandardElements")
    private List<ProductPrice> productPrices = new ArrayList<ProductPrice>();

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "product", targetEntity = ProductPrice.class)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)    
    @MapKeyJoinColumn(name="CURRENCY_ID")
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE, region="ncStandardElements")
    private Map<Currency, ProductPrice> productPriceMap = new HashMap<Currency, ProductPrice>();
```

CRUD ON SERVICE

```
public void removeProductPrice(ProductPrice price){
    Product p = price.getProduct();
    Map<Currency, ProductPrice> productPriceMap = p.getProductPriceMap();
    productPriceMap.remove(price);

    List<ProductPrice> prices = p.getProductPrices();
    prices.remove(price);
    p.setProductPrices(prices);

    p.removeProductPriceMap(price);

    productDao.merge(p);
}

public void saveProductPrice(ProductPrice price, boolean isNew){
    Product p = price.getProduct();
    List<ProductPrice> prices = p.getProductPrices();
    if(isNew ){
        prices.add(price);
    }
    else{
        int i = 0;
        for (ProductPrice tp: prices){
            if (tp.getId() == price.getId()){
                prices.set(i, price);
                break;
            }
            i++;
        }
    }

    p.setProductPrices(prices);
    productDao.merge(p);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that before calling the `removeProductPrice()` you open a session and begin a transaction.

In the `removeProductPrice()` method load the productPrice object to persistence context by doing a get(). Like,

```
ProductPrice price = productPriceDao.get(price.getPriceId());

// Then your logic to delete.
```

I suspect that the passed `ProductPrice` object to the `removeProductPrice()` method is not present in the persistence context of the session.

Can you post the full stack trace which shows the exact line which is causing the exception .

Comment: `productDao.merge(p);` line cause error. I am constantly changing codes and trying other properties. I have solved the problem actually, by defining `FetchType.Eager, FetchType.SUBSELECT` and `CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE` for both relation, however, it is not best configuration for our project. Now, I want to configure relation wihtout `FetchType.Eager`.

Comment: @kirlisakal Did you try the solution i mentioned did it work??

Comment: Actually, now, the case is different. Two relation cause error when you try to crud on `Product` class. After all, I have to add, or remove `Price` from `PriceDao`. The problem is cache in that case. I have solved it by refreshing cache when I get `ProductPrice` list.